# Does Altair support tooltips when exporting in svg format?

Tags: python, svg, tooltip, altair

I tried exporting a [sample graph](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_tooltips.html) with tooltips to SVG, but it seems the tooltips are lost. I could not find any documentation. Is there a way to have tooltips when using SVG?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: tooltips in SVG are implemented via a child `<title>` element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SVG does not support tooltips, so Altair does not include them when exporting to SVG.

(Side note because someone will mention it in the comments: SVG does have a `<title>` attribute that some SVG viewers show when the mouse is hovered over the associated element, but unfortunately it's not really sufficient to handle the complexity of the tooltips created by Altair)